# How to remove thread in AFNetworking library

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, image-uploading

I am using the AFNetworking library for downloading profile picture.
But after successful download of image the thread count not decrementing!

The thread count is 32.

How can I decrement the thread count to zero?

Please suggest

[image: Attached screenshot]

Comment: Could you post the code you use to download the image?

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking open source library. in this original code it show thread issue      Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

What are the other threads doing?

As long as they aren't doing anything and you've cleaned up all your resources correctly, then you probably don't need to care.

An idle thread consumes almost no resources.   And, quite likely, it may be a thread created by the system to service a concurrent dispatch queue (or some other concurrent service request).

If so, then the system will likely reap said threads if they remain idle long enough (while an idle thread doesn't take much resources, constantly destroying and creating threads does).